# How to change database encoding in an Amazon RDS Postgresql instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, encoding

I need to create a database with SQL_ASCII encoding in Amazon RDS PostgreSql database instance.

Since `template0` and `template1` are both with utf8 encoding, I get the following error

```
$ createdb -h endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com -U user -E SQL_ASCII -T template0

createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  encoding "SQL_ASCII" does not match locale "en_US.UTF-8"

DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding "UTF8".
```

In previous versions of Postgresql, `template0` had no predefined encoding, so that command gave no errors.

Also, I don't have permissions to change template1's enconding:

```
postgres=> update pg_database set datistemplate = FALSE where datname = 'template1';
ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_database
```

Although the `\l` command says my user is the owner of `template1`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You must pass a locale that matches your desired encoding and is supported by the host as well. For example, if you don't want localised collations etc, you could pass `--locale=C`. Otherwise you might want `--locale=en_US.ISO-8859-1` (or just `en_US`).